# How to use "find" command with several conditions?

Tags: unix, find

This command will print the *.cpp filenames in the given directory:

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -print
```

How can I print both *.cpp and *.h filenames?

Comment: use -o option as, find . -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
find -regex ".*\.\(cpp\|h\)$"
```

An example with more alternatives:

```
find -regex ".*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\|o\)$"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Use `-o`; see the examples here.](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=find&manpath=Debian+Sid)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If you're doing `-exec` or any other action on the `find` results, remember to parenthese `\( \)` the whole criteria, otherwise `-exec` will apply only to the last `-or`-ed criterion. To work on all of them, parenthese them: `find \( <criterion> -o <criterion> \) -exec <command>`

Answer (score 2):

I'll give an example.
This will search for files with owner=1000 and write them to "uid.list", search for files with group=1000 and write them to "gid.list" and it will skip paths beginning with /proc, /sys, /dev.
The advantage of combined conditions is that filesystem is scanned only once. Here it is:

```
find / \
\( \( -path "/proc" -or -path "/sys" -or -path "/dev" \) -prune \) -or \
\( \( -user 1000 -fprint "uid.list" \)  , 
   \( -group 1000 -fprint "gid.list" \) \)
```

Comment: I think this is way too much information for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -print -o -name "*.h" -print
```